# Anime kids movie about three kids with magical animals only believers could see

Tags: story-identification, anime, magic, animals

There was a kids anime movie I watched 5-10 years ago and it was about these three kids with magical animals only kids could see. There was one girl with a pink based animal. I think one of the boys had a green/blue chameleon.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you ever found the answer but you must be talking about [*"Guardians of the Lost Code"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Lost_Code).

> During a field trip to the history museum, the students Freddy, Atzi,
> and Kimo discover a giant stone disk called the Codex in the storage
> room they are exploring. Three of the brije within it, the deities
> Quetzalcoatl, Ra and Chu Jung, emerge and reveal to them that they are
> the three people chosen to restore the ancestral alliance between
> humans and brijes, an alliance that was fractured with the emergence
> of science and technology.
>
> The brijes are magical animal spirits that have been in contact with
> human beings since the beginning of time. Every human had a brije; the
> human cared for his brije and vice versa. When the human turned 13, a
> human shaman taught both partners a bonding technique that allowed
> them to synchronize and transform into a warrior form, gaining
> extraordinary power allowing them to perform various acts of heroism.
> Unfortunately, with the birth of modern science and technology, this
> union was slowly severed as humans stopped believing in magic, leading
> to tragic results. The brije in the Codex created and sealed
> themselves within it to protect the knowledge of the warrior form
> bonding technique from the forces of darkness that seek it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you [edit] in _why_ you believe this is what the OP is looking for? What points match from the question? Please see [answer] for some more information.